# Device Orientation in iOS 6.0 UINavigationController

Tags: objective-c, ios6, autorotate

I have a UINavigationController in UITabbarcontroller. I want to rotate only one view cotnroller inside UINavigationController.

Here is the code snippet I am using.

```
-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
if (CURRENTDEVICE == IPHONE)
    return [self.navigationController supportedInterfaceOrientations] | UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAllButUpsideDown;
else
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll;
}

-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate {
return YES;
}
```

I have a category on UINavigationController as well:

```
#import "UINavigationController+autorotate.h"

@implementation UINavigationController (autorotate)

- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAllButUpsideDown;
}

@end
```

I am not sure how to implement it.

Answer (score 0):

you can hard code it with cgrect. here is a link to another question that might help you. there is a nice example of hard coding two different views for rotation in there, but i don't recomend it personally. anyhow i thought that might point you to the right direction.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12867792/ios-rotation-causing-views-to-displace-shift-forcing-me-to-use-non-sensical-har

there is a set of codes in that question that might get you started. you also have an option in starboard( if you are using storyboard) to set rotations in IB which is much easier.

hope this helps

adrian

Answer (score 0):

In your category in the `supportedInterfaceOrientations` implementation, you could check for the `topViewController`. You can use `kindOfClass:` method to work out which class it is... Then return a different orientation from the default of your navigation.

You could also subclass `UINavigationController`, and do this check the same way. Subclassing the navigation controller isn't recommended until, iOS 6, the documentation still states this but Apple engineers have told me that with the new rotation logic, you can subclass the `UINavigationController`.